# Filter false, blinking vectors (from findContours)

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm using find contours to find points of interest. I have the image processing pretty much narrowed down, but the resulting vector list returns some false positives. These false positives tend to blink once in a video stream and then disappear and show up somewhere else again. These false positives are expected, but I wonder what algorithm I can use to eliminate them from the vector list, presumably with a list from the previous frame.

I'm using opencv on Android.

What is the algorithm or function I'm looking for called?

Comment: morphologyEx with parameter MORPH_OPEN before calling findContours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this partially by a bitshift_and with a dilated version of the previous frame.